# Display php output on a txt file Linux command line

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line, centos

I currently have a *blacklist.php* file that generates a black list and I need a *blacklist.txt* file on Linux that pulls the output from the PHP file.

Is this possible?

Comment: so you want to write data from php to text file ..of course it is possible

Comment: `file_put_contents`...

Answer (score 11):

If your *blacklist.php* writes output to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), you can run your PHP script like this

```
php blacklist.php > blacklist.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I insert it in windows' scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php
file_put_contents('blacklist.txt ', file_get_contents('blacklist.php'));  
?>
```

**Another alternative:** Use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
<?php
exec ('php blacklist.php', $output); 
file_put_contents('blacklist.txt', $output); 
?>
```

**Another alternative**:`Output redirection to a text file using Command line`

In **Windows**:

```
C:\xampp\php>php C:\xampp\htdocs\blacklist.php >blacklist.txt
```

In **Linux**:

```
$ php blacklist.php >blacklist.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file_put_contents()`:

`file_put_contents('your file', 'your data')`

Answer (score 1):

Just run the script and redirect it to the .txt file. Something like

```
php blacklist.php > blacklist.txt
```